# Vendor dll attempted to read or write from protected memory on execution

Tags: c#

I have a poorly documented .DLL from a vendor who does not like to help us. They would rather sell us their on solutions, so I am stymied.

I am trying to receive a status word.

```
[DllImport ("xxx.dll")]
static extern IntPtr name_of_function();
```

The documentation says the function returns a pointer to an integer (16 bits).

calling:
    IntPtr statusReturn = name_of_function();

Upon execution I get the attempted to read or write protected memory...

Target system is WinXP, because that's what we have on our test systems, still.

I have set the processor to x86

Comment: With only that info is impossible for anyone to help you as nobody can see what's happening there, the most probable is the function definition is wrong, but without seeing the exact library and function definitions is just guessing. Maybe instead of a pointer it returns the short directly, try to change the return type to ushort.

Comment: What additional information is needed? Am I creating the function correctly? And, am I calling the function correctly?

Comment: *Am I creating the function correctly? And, am I calling the function correctly?* Impossible to tell without the sdk documentation